Integration of f=1/r on arbitrary triangle in 3D
Problem:
I want to integrate the function f=1/||x-y|| on a triangle which is defined by some vertices v1,v2,v3 in Euclidean 3D space. The singularity sits at x.
Question:
How can I compute this integral efficiently for arbitrary triangles and singularity positions in python? Is scipy suitable?
import numpy as np

# position of the singularity
x = np.array([0, 0, 1])

# triangle vertices
v1 = np.array([0, 1, 0])
v2 = np.array([1, 0, 0])
v3 = np.array([0, 0, 0])

# example for the evaluation of the function for the point pair x, y
y = np.array([0, 1, 0])
val = 1/np.linalg.norm(x-y)

# compute integral on triangle
integral = ?


What is your coordinates system? Euclidean in 3D? Barycentric? What is the integration variable? y? Then how come it isn't in the triangle? (At least not in any coordinate system I can think of)?

Euclidean 3D. Yes the integration variable is y. y can be on the triangle. The val = 1/np.linalg.norm(x-y) example was just to show how the value is computed.

"can" be on the triangle? Or "must"? I mean, if you are integrating on the triangle, that means that y value iterates the whole triangle (and only the triangle), right?

Yes you are correct. "must".

I changed the text in the original post and position of y to [0,1,0] to avoid this confusion.

isn't scipy.integrate.dblquad what you need?

I believe so but I do not know how to use it correctly here. Also I think its not that trivial if the singularity sits on the triangle?

Using pure numpy
import numpy as np

# position of the singularity
x = np.array([0, 0, 1])

# triangle vertices
v1 = np.array([0, 1, 0])
v2 = np.array([1, 0, 0])
v3 = np.array([0, 0, 0])

# compute integral on triangle
# Number of discretisation point on each axis (there are 2 axis for the surface: v2-v1 and v3-v1)
ns=1000
# I represent coordinates in triangle system: a point u,v is v1+u(v2-v1)+v(v3-v1)
# So, v1 is (0,0). v2 is (1,0), v3 is (0,1)...
# Any pair (u,v) within [0,1]×[0,1] is inside the triangle
# To let numpy do the for loop for me (never ever pure python for loop for this kind of thing)
# I use 2 dimensions. One for u, One for v. 
# Later I'll add a 3rd for the x,y,z values
# u alone use only the first dimension
u=np.linspace(0,1,ns,0)[:,None]
# Likewise, v alone use the second
# Also, note the 4th parameter of linspace: 0 (or False)
# That mean that 1 is excluded. We don't want to count both boundaries
# infinitesimal surface starting just before 1, and ending at 1 must
# be the last one
v=np.linspace(0,1,ns,0)[None,:]

# Note that u+v>=1 we are outside the triangle
inside = (u+v)<1

# The two direction vectors of my coordinate system
v21=v2-v1
v31=v3-v1

# y is a 3d array (obtained by broadcasting)
# such as, for a scalars u,v, y[u,v] is a 1D array representing `y`
# euclidean coordinates
y = v1[None,None,:]+u[...,None]*v21[None,None,:]+v[...,None]*v31[None,None,:]
# dS is just a scalar: it is the area of an elementary paralellogram
dS = np.linalg.norm(np.cross(v21,v31))/ns**2

# So, this is the 2d array of values to integrate. One for each pair (u,v)
# (0 when (u,v) is outside the triangle)
val = inside/np.linalg.norm(x-y, axis=2)
print(val.sum()*dS)

Explanation are in comments (the hardest part is to understand comments. Ouside that it is a pretty simple code. It just sum all possible val for each possible (well, a subsample of them, of course. A discretization) position in the triangle.
Because I use v2-v1 and v3-v1 as coordinate system, dS is not just 1/ns², but that is just a scalar factor.
The only real computation are in the 2 last lines (I could have merged them into 1, but I wanted to keep your val).
It computes 1/np.linalg.norm(x-y) for all y (for all (u,v))
(but does it a vectorized way: y is a 2d array of points — so a 3d array —, and we let linalg.norm compute norm on each of them — axis=2 — and do that for loop for us).
And then, likewise, the sum is done vectorized on an array of such val.
Note that this could be optimized using other libraries. Or iterating explicitly with numba. Since I iterate twice too much values: half of the (u,v) pairs, that is of y array are outside the triangle (but does not contribute to the sum because that the half for which inside is 0).
But that cost is really nothing compared to the one of using for loop ourselves (if we did write the for loop ourselves, we could have for u in linspace(0,1) and then for v in linspace(0,1-u), and never iterate outside the triangle. But cost of doing that in pure python is way more (hundred of times more) that cost of integrating on the whole paralelogram whose your triangle is a half. In numba, that would be another story).
Using dblquad
scipy does indeed have a function for that. But it is easier to understand it now that we understand what it does, and why those gfun hfun are indeed useful. The hard part of the previous work we did for pure numpy integration is still needed here. dblquad spares only the summation part (which it probably does with some more clever way than regular discretisation and iteration).
We still need to figure out how to represent our function as a function a 2 scalar variables, that is how to iterate the surface.
We already did that, so we can replace the 2 last lines of the previous code by dblquad equivalent
import scipy
def func(u,v):
    y=u*v21+v*v31
    return ns*ns*dS/np.linalg.norm(x-y)

print(scipy.integrate.dblquad(func, 0, 1, 0, lambda u: 1-u))

Again, easy, but that replaces just 2 other lines. You still need to find a way to integrate with a double loop. That is what makes necessary the choice of another coordinate system (in the triangle plane), otherwise you can't know how to iterate 3 coordinates to integrate on a plane surface.
And if you keep mine in dblquad (which is useful to compute easily the boundaries) then, you need to take into account the deformation. dblquad has no way to know that this (u,v) pair represent a point in a non-square grid. Hence the ns*ns*dS factor (ns*ns is to undo the /ns**2 of dS computation. Point in ns*ns*dS is the ratio between the area of the integrated surface — the whole paralellogram — and the apparent area of (u,v) domain, so [0,1]×[0,1]). In your example, that ratio is 1 tho
Consideration on speed and accuracy
Generally speaking, I do not encourage reinventing the wheel, except for pedagogical reasons : one make better usage of existing wheels, when they understand how a wheel work, and the better way to understand that is to reinvent it once, and then never use it and use existing wheels instead.
So, dblquad is probably better than pure numpy version, which is just a basic integration scheme.
That being said

It is not fast. Well, it shoudn't.
Here it is suspiciously fast. And since we pass it python's lambda (or functions), it should be slower than numpy version (for loop is in scipy C code. But each iteration requires a call python interpreter, which is slow). So explanation is that it does not as many iteration (edit: I've just counted; it does some 441 sampling, compared to my 1000000 in numpy). So reason why it is fast here (faster than my numpy, is just because it works 2200 times less).

Result is in same order of magnitude but not identical. My code returns 0.437 for your example, while dblquad returns 0.397

And reality is 0.437. So, in this case, my numpy code is right, dblquad is wrong (well, is off).
I haven't computed the exact result ; it implies the integration of a arcsinh((1-x)/√(1+x²)). But at least, I can reduce the double integration to a single one.
And ∫∫ 1/(1+x²+y²)dxdy on that triangle is
∫ arcsinh((1-x)/√(1+x²)).dx when x is in [0,1]
And that is just a 1d-integration, that you can numerically compute with a practically infinite accuracy.
And it is 0.437

So direct numpy integration gives a way better result than dblquad. But slower.
But again, that is because dblquad just computed 441 value of the function to integrate. Btw, 441 is 21². That cannot be a coincidence.

If I know use numpy to integrate on only 21×21 discretisation (so, ns=21), as dblquad. Numpy returns 0.467.
That is now quit off to. But only 0.03 off the real result, while dblquad, with the same amount of computation is 0f by 0.04.
And besides, dblquad takes 100 times more than my numpy version, now that they compute both the same amount of samples.


So
Conclusion

dblquad is way slower when it uses the same number of sample. Which make sense: it is still pure python; only the for loop is internal scypy code ; what is inside the loop isn't. When numpy version vectorize everything: the loop to sum val, but also the computation of val.

I suppose that the people who wrote dblquad did a smarter job than my simple regular numpy integration, and that it has, generally speaking a smarter strategy to have good accuracy with fewer sampling. But in this very case, even that isn't true. Acuracy is mediocre (even tho default tolerance parameters promised way better). It should, with default tolerance, have increased the sampling. And even with the same sampling, in this case, simple summation does better.


So I guess the conclusion is "don't use dblquad" if speed and acurracy is important.

You still need to figure out how to make your problem the integration of a 2 variable functions over a domain
It will be slow, because of the pure python lambda that you need to pass. Unless you pass a ufunc... but most ufunc have a well known direct primitive, so nobody just integrates a ufunc.
Acuracy is not way better for the same amount of sampling. And at least, doing it yourself with numpy, you control the sampling (with dblquad you control the error, which is better. But obviously it does not work that well)

I am pretty sure dlbquad is smarter than I am, and find some very elaborate way to discretize, compared to my regular one.
But 441 is really not a lot (it is 21², btw. Unless it is a coincidence, the fact that it is a square seems to indicate that it is just a discretisation of u and v, like I did, with less points), especially when the function to integrate is opaque to it. So, I would be that my numpy result is closer to the reality
